# SSRS 2008 - Where is the Report Footer?

Tags: reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2008

I'm just beginning to learn SSRS 2008. I've used many other report writers, and most, if not all, had the ability to create report headers and footers (in addition to page headers/footers). I can't see to find a way to create a report footer.

In the report I'm creating, I would like to include some information on the very last page of the report, and only the last page. Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page top aligned report header does not exist and page bottom aligned report footer does not exist in SSRS. Only way to get information only on the first page is to place it before any data regions (like table) and way to get information only on the last page is to place it after all data regions (like table).

Answer (score 1):

If you add a Grouping or Edit the exciting one. You should see a Show Footer and Show Header section. If you do not see it than there is something wrong with your data table. Use the Tool and add a new data table by default it should have a Heading and Footer. Go to the following blog for beginner to SSRS. 
http://ssrsdeveloper.blogspot.com/